# What is the syntax error? My code returns:SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<MYCODE>, line) ?,?

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to define a function that will eliminate non-unique elements from a list; and then check for equality against a second list.

```
def checkio(data):
        data = []
        data = set(data)
        if len(data) > 0:
            return data

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        assert isinstance(checkio([1]),list) "The result must be a list"
        assert checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3] 
        assert checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [] 
        assert checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] 
        assert checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

Comment: There are only 12 lines here! What is there on the 19th line?

Comment: You do realize that the first assignment overwrites the argument `data`

Comment: A shorter way to write this _checkio_ function: `checkio = lambda data: None`.

Comment: @Matthias How is that? Returning `None` every time makes no sense.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: I meant the function from the OPs code, not the correct version.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `d` in def:

```
def checkio(data):
```

and a paren:

```
  assert isinstance(checkio([1]), "The result must be a list") # <-
```

Even with those fixes, your isinstance is wrong, the second arg should be a class or type.

You also use data as the parameter name and then set `data = []` so you always have an empty list.

This seems to be what you are trying to do using a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict to find non unique values:

```
from collections import Counter


def checkio(data):
    # get count of each element in data
    cn = Counter(data)
    # keep elements from data that are non unique
    # iterating over data to keep the order
    return [k for k in data if cn[k] > 1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # isinstance needs a class or type 
    assert isinstance(checkio([1]), list)
    assert checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3]
    assert checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == []
    assert checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    assert checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

Presuming you actually wanted your asserts to pass.

Comment: Please change the first statement to something like "*functions in python are defined using `def`*". It is sounding a bit absurd.

Comment: @BhargavRao Actually, I like that as an opening for an answer. More answers should open that way. :P

Comment: @BhargavRao, was too busy fixing all the errors, syntax and logically

Comment: @Padraic Yep. Good to see that you've fixed the indent error too!